# iOS8 today extension install error

Tags: ios, ios-app-group

I install my App with today extension, then add the extension, then I uninstall the app and reinstall it. The today extension get empty data from app group or the plist in main bundle,it is a iOS bug?

Comment: Please expand on what error you are getting

Comment: not error,but i restart the device,it is show right,i have no idea with it ,I am not sure it is a iOS Bug?